# Url login on Moodle

Tags: authentication, plugins, moodle, tweak

I would like to make it possible to redirect users from a site to my Moodle installation, providing two encrypted parameters in the url. Based on these parameter, Moodle should authenticate the users and grant or refuse access.

Is anyone familiar with this, and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Should I build a new plug-in, modify index.php ? Both ?

Basically the php code to process the GET-parameters is ready, but I don't know how and where to insert it in the Moodle code.

Cheers for helping, much appreciated

Paul

Comment: Paul what you exact want.. login from your application and automatic get looged in your moodle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem solved many times before. The best option for doing it securely is to use one of the existing auth plugins. If the sites are on the same server or you are happy to allow direct database access so that Moodle can read the password hashes from your other site's DB, then you can use db auth, which is simplest. Otherwise, you'll need some sort of cookie based one. I've used CAS authentication before, but shibboleth is also an option. This may seem like overkill, but really, it isn't. Just having auth tokens in the url leaves you open to brute force password-guessing attacks, so the challenge-response mechanism that these plugins provide is very important.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, you pointed me in the right direction. In the end I used shibboleth and it now works fine. Cheers!

Comment: is it possible to make something that allows students from any school that uses moodle to login using their moodle sign in?  For example I have a college book rental app , id like to have a "sign in with moodle" button. Possible?